# It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation, distutils, pyyaml

On `pip3 uninstall -y pyyaml` I get error:

```
Found existing installation: PyYAML 5.3.1
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Is there any way to force uninstall or any other way to fix this problem?